# autogenerated keys for grails 2.4.3

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails

The problem has been solved. The problem was that I used jdbc3. Using jdbc4 solves the problem!

I have upgraded from grails 2.3.6 to grails 2.4.3.
This meant changing from hibernate 3.6.10.3 to hibernate 3.6.10.17.
I use a postgresql database with a sequence to generate an id for all objects:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence;

CREATE TABLE betygstyp (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('hibernate_sequence'),
...
```

I hope not to have to change the database which has worked nicely before (with grails 2.3.6 etc.)

When I now try to save a new object I get this error message:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Returning autogenerated keys is not supported.
>   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.prepareStatement(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:448)

I have also tried this with hibernate 4.3.5.5 which gives the same problem.

I suspect there is some new configuration needed but what?
I use the default configuration used in Grails and do not use any xml configuration for hibernate.

Comment: Did you try to use `bigserial` instead of a default with nextval?

Comment: Btw: it must have been more than just upgrading from jdbc3 to jdbc4: `getGeneratedKeys()` works fine in postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar, postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc3.jar postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc3.jar and postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate may have changed the strategy for bypassing the postgresql shortcomings. There is no support in postgresql JDBC3 driver to automatically resend the id generated by the sequence.
If the strategy is changed to using standard SQL

```
insert into betygstyp (...) values (...) returning id
```

then an upgrade to the latest version of the JDBC4 driver may solve the problem. In fact, I know from direct contact with @inge that it did.

Comment: "*There is no support in postgres to automatically resend the id generated by the sequence*" - That is simply not true. `getGeneratedKeys()` works just fine in Postgres when using `prepareStatement("...", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)`

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I should rephrase to "There is no support in postgresql JDBC3 driver to ...

Comment: Works for me using `postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc3.jar` just as well.

Comment: It doesn't for me neither with postgresql-jdbc3-9.1.jar nor postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc3.jar and java-7-openjdk-amd64 or java-8-oracle but on my old server with postgresql-jdbc3-9.1.jar and java-6-openjdk it works. Application is built on Grails and Groovy and I see no purpose in tweaking Hibernate, so I allow Hibernate to autogenerate all queries.

Comment: Then that seems a Hibernate/Grails/Groovy bug rather than a problem with the JDBC driver.